# No consigo que se guardan datos en un arrayList

Tags: java

tengo un problema que no logro solucionar, no consigo que se guarden los objetos "Socio" en el ArrayList, pero haciendo pruebas, los datos llegan a su clase, pero no se porque no se guarda. A continuacion pongo ambas clases. Posiblemente se pueda hacer mejor, pero aun estoy aprendiendo.
Necesito guardar los datos para mostrarlos en la clase principal
Una aclaracion: Los socios se crean a la par que los jugadores porque los jugadores necesitan ser socios antes.
Despues de darle horas y horas vueltas a este tema una y otra vez, vengo aqui en busca de ayuda. Muchas gracias por vuestro tiempo

```
public class Jugador extends Persona {

    private int dorsal = 0;
    private int NumPartidos = 0;
    
    //ArrayList
    private ArrayList<Partido> ListaPartidos;
    private ArrayList<Partido> Estadistica;
    private ArrayList<Jugador> ListaJugadores;
    
    private int PARTIDOS_TEMPORADA = 15; //Numero de temporadas
    private String temporada []= new String[PARTIDOS_TEMPORADA];

    //Constructor
    public Jugador(String nombre, String apellidos, String DNI, String CuentaBancaria,int dorsal,int NumPartidos) 
    {
        super(nombre, apellidos, DNI, CuentaBancaria);
        this.dorsal = dorsal;
        this.NumPartidos = NumPartidos;
        this.ListaPartidos = new ArrayList<Partido>();
        this.Estadistica = new ArrayList<Partido>();
        this.ListaJugadores = new ArrayList<Jugador>();
    }
    
    //Constructor vacio
    public Jugador()
    {
        this.dorsal = 0;
        this.NumPartidos = 0;
        this.ListaPartidos = new ArrayList<Partido>();
        this.Estadistica = new ArrayList<Partido>();
        this.ListaJugadores = new ArrayList<Jugador>();
    }

    //Getters y setters
    public int getDorsal() {
        return dorsal;
    }

    public ArrayList<Partido>ListaPartidos() {
        return ListaPartidos;
    }
    
    public int getNumPartidos() {
        return NumPartidos;
    }

    public void setDorsal(int dorsal) 
    {
        this.dorsal = dorsal;
    }

    public void setListaPartidos(ArrayList<Partido> EstadisticaJugador)
    {
        
        this.ListaPartidos = EstadisticaJugador;
    }
    
    public void setNumPartidos(int numPartidos) 
    {
        this.NumPartidos = numPartidos;
    }
    
    public ArrayList<Partido> getEstadistica() {
        return Estadistica;
    }

    public void setEstadistica(ArrayList<Partido> Estadistica) {
        this.Estadistica = Estadistica;
    }
    
    public ArrayList<Jugador> getListaJugadores() {
        return ListaJugadores;
    }

    public void setListaJugadores(ArrayList<Jugador> listaJugadores) {
        ListaJugadores = listaJugadores;
    }
    
    //Metodo para crear objetos socios y jugadores.
    public void nuevoSocio() //Metodo para crear socios
    {
        String nombre,apellido,DNI,IBAN;
        int NumPartidos = 0;
        double cuota;
        
        

        for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) 
        {
            Socio socio = new Socio();
            
            System.out.println();
            System.out.print("Nombre: ");
            System.out.println(nombre = Persona.generarNombre());

            System.out.print("Apellido: ");
            System.out.println(apellido = Persona.generarApellido());

            System.out.print("DNI: ");
            System.out.println(DNI = Persona.generaDNI());

            System.out.print("Cuenta bancaria: ");
            System.out.println(IBAN = Persona.generaIBAN());

            System.out.print("Cuota de socio: ");
            System.out.println(cuota = Math.random()*(700 )+400); 

            System.out.print("Dorsal como jugador: ");
            System.out.println((this.dorsal++)+1);
            
            ListaJugadores.add(new Jugador(nombre,apellido,DNI,IBAN,dorsal,NumPartidos));
            
            Socio socioAux = new Socio(nombre,apellido,DNI,IBAN,cuota);
            
            socio.AgregarSocio(socioAux);
        }
    }
    
    //Metodo para comprobar el dorsal introducido sea valido
    //Ayudara a ver los datos exclusivos del dorsal escojido
    public Jugador ComprobarDorsal(int dorsal) 
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < ListaJugadores.size(); i++) 
        {
            Jugador jugador = ListaJugadores.get(i);
                        
            if ( jugador.getDorsal() == dorsal)
            {
//              System.out.println(dorsalAux);
                return jugador;
            }
        }
        return null;
    }

    //Metodo que agregara un objeto partido en un arraylist
    public void AgregarPartido(Partido p, boolean participar)
    {
        if(participar)
        {
            this.NumPartidos++; //Sumara +1 al objeto jugador que haya partricipado en el partido.
            ListaPartidos.add(p);
        }
        else
        {
            ListaPartidos.add(p);
        }
    }
    
    public void AgregarEstadistica(Partido p)
    {
        this.Estadistica.add(p);
    }

    //Metodo que mostrara los partidos jugados y sus datos
    public void muestraPartidos(int dorsal) 
    {
        for(int i = 0; i < ComprobarDorsal(dorsal).ListaPartidos.size(); i++)
        {
            if(ComprobarDorsal(dorsal).ListaPartidos.get(i).getValObtenido() > -1)
            {
                System.out.println("Nombre del equipo rival: " + ComprobarDorsal(dorsal).ListaPartidos.get(i).getNomEquipo());
                System.out.println("Minutos jugados: "+ComprobarDorsal(dorsal).ListaPartidos.get(i).getMinJugados());
                System.out.println("Puntos conseguidos: "+ComprobarDorsal(dorsal).ListaPartidos.get(i).getPunConseguidos());
                System.out.println("Rebotes: "+ComprobarDorsal(dorsal).ListaPartidos.get(i).getNumRebotes());
                System.out.println("Asistencias: "+ComprobarDorsal(dorsal).ListaPartidos.get(i).getNumAsistencias());
                System.out.println("Tapones: "+ComprobarDorsal(dorsal).ListaPartidos.get(i).getNumTapones());
                System.out.println("Valoracion obtenida: "+ComprobarDorsal(dorsal).ListaPartidos.get(i).getValObtenido() + "\n");
            }
        }
    }

    //Metodo que mostrara la estadistica de cada jugador en los partidos jugados
    public void mostrarEstadisticas(int dorsal) 
    {
        for(int i = 0; i < ComprobarDorsal(dorsal).Estadistica.size(); i++)
        {
            if(ComprobarDorsal(dorsal).ListaPartidos.get(i).getValObtenido() > -1)
            {
                System.out.println("Nombre del equipo rival: " + ComprobarDorsal(dorsal).ListaPartidos.get(i).getNomEquipo());
                System.out.println("Porcentaje de minutos jugados: " + (ComprobarDorsal(dorsal).ListaPartidos.get(i).getMinJugados()*100)/ComprobarDorsal(dorsal).Estadistica.get(i).getMinJugados() +"%");
                System.out.println("Porcentaje de puntos conseguidos: "+(ComprobarDorsal(dorsal).ListaPartidos.get(i).getPunConseguidos()*100)/ComprobarDorsal(dorsal).Estadistica.get(i).getPunConseguidos() + "%");
                System.out.println("Porcentaje de rebotes: " + (ComprobarDorsal(dorsal).ListaPartidos.get(i).getNumRebotes()*100)/ComprobarDorsal(dorsal).Estadistica.get(i).getNumRebotes() +  "%");
                System.out.println("Porcentaje de asistencias: " + (ComprobarDorsal(dorsal).ListaPartidos.get(i).getNumAsistencias()*100)/ComprobarDorsal(dorsal).Estadistica.get(i).getNumAsistencias() + "%");
                System.out.println("Porcentaje de tapones: " + (ComprobarDorsal(dorsal).ListaPartidos.get(i).getNumTapones()*100)/ComprobarDorsal(dorsal).Estadistica.get(i).getNumTapones() +"%");
                System.out.println("Porcentaje de valoracion obtenida: " + (ComprobarDorsal(dorsal).ListaPartidos.get(i).getValObtenido()*100)/ComprobarDorsal(dorsal).Estadistica.get(i).getValObtenido() + "%\n");

            }
            
        }
    }
    
    public void nuevoPartido()  //Metodo que permitira jugar la temporada de 15 partidos
    {
        int minJugados, puntosOb, rebotes, asistencias, tapones = 0, valoracionOb;

        if (ListaJugadores.size() == 0)
        {
            System.err.println("No hay jugadores para jugar partidos");
        }
        else if(ListaJugadores.size() < 10)
        {
            System.err.println("Se necesitan minimo 10 jugadores. Actualmente hay: " + ListaJugadores.size() + " jugadores.");
        }
        else
        {
            for (int i = 0;i<PARTIDOS_TEMPORADA;i++) 
            {
                {
                    int minJugadosTotal = 0,puntosObTotal = 0,rebotesTotal = 0,
                            asistenciasTotal = 0,taponesTotal = 0,valoracionObTotal = 0;

                    System.out.println("\nPartido "+(i+1));
                    //              String nomEquipo = ent.nextLine();
                    String nomEquipo = Partido.nombresEquipos();

                    System.out.println("Nombre del equipo rival: " + nomEquipo);

                    temporada[i] = nomEquipo;

                    for (int j = 0; j < ListaJugadores.size(); j++) //Se guarda la informacion de cada partido en cada jugador
                    {
                        Jugador jugadorAux = ListaJugadores.get(j);

                        //booleano que segun el numero, se encontrara en un estado u otro
                        boolean participacion;
                        Random random = new Random(); //Se genera un booleano random para hacer si un jugador ha jugado o no un partido
                        participacion = random.nextBoolean();

                        minJugados = (int)(Math.random()*60+1);

                        puntosOb = (int)(Math.random()*45+1);

                        rebotes = (int)(Math.random()*15+1);

                        asistencias = (int)(Math.random()*10+1);

                        tapones = (int)(Math.random()*10+1);

                        valoracionOb = (int)(Math.random()*50+1);


                        if(participacion) //Siempre que el booleano sea true se guardaran los datos del partido
                        {
                            participacion = true;
                            jugadorAux.AgregarPartido(new Partido(nomEquipo, minJugados, puntosOb, rebotes, asistencias, 
                                    tapones, valoracionOb),participacion);

                            //Se guardara por cada partido jugado, el valor de todos los jugadores, se utilizara para comprobar la estadistica de cada jugador
                            
                            minJugadosTotal += minJugados;

                            puntosObTotal += puntosOb;

                            rebotesTotal += rebotes;

                            asistenciasTotal += asistencias;

                            taponesTotal += tapones;

                            valoracionObTotal += valoracionOb;
                        }

                        else
                        {
                            participacion = false;
                            jugadorAux.AgregarPartido(new Partido("", 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, -1),participacion); //Se guardan datos en negativo, para que no cuenta como partido jugado
                        }
                    }
                    for (int k = 0; k < this.ListaJugadores.size(); k++) //Se guarda por cada jugador, el total de la estadistica de cada partido.
                    {
                        Jugador jugadorAux = ListaJugadores.get(k);
                        jugadorAux.AgregarEstadistica(new Partido(nomEquipo,minJugadosTotal,puntosObTotal,rebotesTotal,asistenciasTotal,taponesTotal,valoracionObTotal));
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
    
    public void mayorParticipacion() //Calcula el jugador con mayor participacion. Devuelve el dorsal del jugador con mayor participacion
    {
        int NumPartidos = 0;
        int dorsal = 0;
        String nombre = "",apellido = "";
        for (int i = 0;i<this.ListaJugadores.size();i++) 
        {
            if(this.ListaJugadores.get(i).NumPartidos >= NumPartidos)
            {
                NumPartidos = ListaJugadores.get(i).getNumPartidos();
                dorsal = ListaJugadores.get(i).getDorsal();
                nombre = ListaJugadores.get(i).getNombre();
                apellido = ListaJugadores.get(i).getApellidos();
            }
        }
        System.out.println("\nEl jugador con mayor participacion: " + NumPartidos + "\nNombre: " + nombre + "\nApellido: " + apellido + "\nDorsal: " + dorsal+"\n");
    }

    public void mayorPuntuacion() //Calcula el jugador con mayor participacion. Devuelve el dorsal del jugador con mayor puntuacion
    {
        int puntuacion = 0;
        int dorsal = 0;
        String nombre = "",apellido = "";
        for (int i = 0;i<this.ListaJugadores.size();i++) 
        {
            Jugador jugador = ListaJugadores.get(i);
            if(jugador.getEstadistica().get(i).getValObtenido() > puntuacion)
            {
                puntuacion = jugador.getEstadistica().get(i).getPunConseguidos();
                dorsal = ListaJugadores.get(i).getDorsal();
                nombre = ListaJugadores.get(i).getNombre();
                apellido = ListaJugadores.get(i).getApellidos();
            }
        }
        System.out.println("\nEl jugador con mayor puntuacion: " + puntuacion + "\nNombre: " + nombre + "\nApellido: " + apellido + "\nDorsal: " + dorsal+"\n");
    }

    public void mayorValoracion() //Calcula el jugador con mayor participacion. Devuelve el dorsal del jugador con mayor puntuacion
    {
        double valoracion = 0;
        int dorsal = 0;
        String nombre = "",apellido = "";
        for (int i = 0;i<this.ListaJugadores.size();i++) 
        {
            Jugador jugador = ListaJugadores.get(i);
            if(jugador.getEstadistica().get(i).getValObtenido() > valoracion)
            {
                valoracion = jugador.getEstadistica().get(i).getValObtenido();
                dorsal = ListaJugadores.get(i).getDorsal();
                nombre = ListaJugadores.get(i).getNombre();
                apellido =ListaJugadores.get(i).getApellidos();
            }
        }
        System.out.println("\nEl jugador con mayor valoracion: " + valoracion + "\nNombre: " + nombre + "\nApellido: " + apellido + "\nDorsal: " + dorsal+"\n");
    }
    
    public Jugador buscarJugador(int dorsal) //Funcion que servira para comprobar segun el dorsal introducido los datos de los partidos jugados
    {
        for (int i = 0;i<this.ListaJugadores.size();i++) 
        {
            if(ListaJugadores.get(i).getDorsal() == dorsal)
            {
                return ListaJugadores.get(i);
            }
        }
        return null;
    }
    
    public String toString ()
    {
        return "Nombre del jugador: "+this.getNombre() + "\nApellidos: "+this.getApellidos()+"\nDNI: "
                +this.getDNI()+"\nDorsal: "+(this.getDorsal()) + "\nHa jugado: "+this.getNumPartidos() + "\n";
    }
}
```

```
public class Socio extends Persona{

    private final double cuota;
    private ArrayList<Socio> ListaSocios;

    public Socio(String nombre, String apellidos, String DNI, String CuentaBancaria, double cuota) 
    {
        super(nombre, apellidos, DNI, CuentaBancaria);
        this.cuota = cuota;
        this.ListaSocios = new ArrayList<Socio>();
    }
    
    public Socio()
    {
        this.cuota = 0;
        this.ListaSocios = new ArrayList<Socio>();
    }

    //Los getters y setters
    public double getCuota() {
        return cuota;
    }
    
    public ArrayList<Socio> getListaSocios() {
        return ListaSocios;
    }

    public void setListasocios(ArrayList<Socio> listaSocios) {
        this.ListaSocios = listaSocios;
    }
    
    public void AgregarSocio(Socio s)
    {
        this.ListaSocios.add(s);
    }
    
    public String toString()
    {
        return "\nNombre: "+this.getNombre()+"\nApellidos: "+this.getApellidos()+"\nDNI: "+this.getDNI()
                + "\nCuota: "+this.getCuota()+"\nCuentaBancaria: "+this.getCuentaBancaria() + "\n";
    }
}
```

He modificado la clase socio y ni aun asi
(NUEVA MODIFICACION)

```
public class Socio extends Persona{

    private double cuota;
    private ArrayList<Socio> ListaSocios = new ArrayList<Socio>();

    public Socio(String nombre, String apellidos, String DNI, String CuentaBancaria, double cuota) 
    {
        super(nombre, apellidos, DNI, CuentaBancaria);
        this.cuota = cuota;
    }
    
    public Socio()
    {
        this.cuota = 0;
    }

    //Los getters y setters
    public double getCuota() {
        return cuota;
    }


    public void setCuota(double cuota) 
    {
        
        this.cuota = cuota;
    }


    public ArrayList<Socio> getListaSocios() 
    {
        return this.ListaSocios;
    }

    public void setListaSocios(ArrayList<Socio> listaSocios) 
    {
        this.ListaSocios = listaSocios;
    }

     public void AgregarSocio(Socio s)
    {

        Socio socioAux = new Socio(s.getNombre(),s.getApellidos(),s.getDNI(),s.getCuentaBancaria(),s.getCuota());
        
        System.out.println(socioAux.toString());
        
        ListaSocios.add(socioAux);
    }
    
    public String toString()
    {
        return "\nNombre: "+this.getNombre()+"\nApellidos: "+this.getApellidos()+"\nDNI: "+this.getDNI()
                + "\nCuota: "+this.getCuota()+"\nCuentaBancaria: "+this.getCuentaBancaria() + "\n";
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Tu problema esta en el constructor `socio`, en ambos exactamente. Cada vez que inicializas un nuevo socio ya sea con el constructor vacío o con todos sus parámetros estas inicializando el `ArrayList ListaSocios` a 0. Lo que tienes que hacer es inicializar  el `ArrayList ListaSocios` fuera del constructor como parámetro global de la clase, ya lo tienes declarado pero te faltaría inicializarlo.

```
 private ArrayList<Socio> ListaSocios = new ArrayList<Socio>();
```

Los constructores quedarían tal que así:

```
 public Socio(String nombre, String apellidos, String DNI, String CuentaBancaria, double cuota) 
{
    super(nombre, apellidos, DNI, CuentaBancaria);
    this.cuota = cuota;
}
public Socio()
{
    this.cuota = 0;
}
```

Y con el metodo `public void AgregarSocio(Socio s)` desde la clase donde crees el socio acto seguido llamas a la función y lo añades a la lista.

Comment: me sigue sin funcionar. Lo hice tal como dices, voy a editarlo para que lo veas